# Django Form does not save properly

Tags: python, django

I want to create a comment system. I can take `username`, `doc_id`, and `comp_name`, but I cannot get the `comment_others`. I think there is a problem saving the form. How can I fix it?

**views.py**

```
def ocr(request, id):
    pdf = get_object_or_404(Pdf, id=id)
    approval = ApprovalProcess(user_id=request.user, highest_rank=1)
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_2 = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=pdf)

        if form_2.is_valid():
            form_2.instance.username=request.user
            form_2.instance.comp_name = userP[0].company
            form_2.instance.doc_id = pdf
            form_2.save()

    else:
        form_2 = CommentForm()

    comment_obj = CommentFromOthers.objects.filter(doc_id=pdf).order_by("-created_date")

.....
```

**models.py**

```
class CommentFromOthers(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    comment_others = RichTextField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comments = RichTextField

    class Meta:
        model = CommentFromOthers
        fields = ('comment_others',)
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <div class="card-title">Risk Rating & Credit Limit</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            {% for comment in comment_obj %}
                                        <li>
                                            <h5>{{ comment.username }} - {{ comment.created_date }}</h5>
                                            <h4>{{ comment.comment_others|safe}}</h4>
                                        </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                            </div>
```

And there are two forms on the same page. When I save this form, the other form disappears. Why it could be happening?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PdfRiskForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pdf)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        ...
        approval.save()

else:
    form = PdfRiskForm()
```

Note: `RichTextField` is the text field of django-ckeditor. But the problem is not relevant to that because when I change it as charfield it still doesn't save the `comment_others` field.

Comment: `comment_others.save()` and `form_2.save()`, why save two times? save only the form, if you want to set some fields write something like `form_2.instance.username=request.user` before saving

Comment: Because form doesn't save and I tried to do somethings but I failed obviously.  Now I try to use instance but the form still doesn't save.

Comment: Have you checked that `form_2` is valid? And tried to print the values of `comment_others` and `form_2` before saving? I would think that at least `form_2` tries to save an incomplete model, since several required model fields appear to be missing in the modelform.

Comment: Please show your template where you render `form_2`.

Comment: `CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=pdf)` why do you pass the `Pdf` instance when the form is for the `CommentFromOthers` model??

Comment: @00 I checked it is valid and it saves all fields except commt_others. Should I try charfield instead of ckeditor?

Comment: Yes, your edit changed the instantiation of `form_2` a bit; but that does cause confusion at to what your actual code looks like.

Comment: You're not showing what `RichTextField` is; we have to guess. Does it come from https://pypi.org/project/django-richtextfield/ ? Please update your question to add the relevant info about RichTextField; you indicate this may be the problem, since comment_others doesn't get saved, but then there is no information about the specific field type this field is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.py

```
comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_2 = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=id) #or user.id

    if form_2.is_valid():
        
        form_2.save()
```

by eliminating those lines in views.py will automatically save the fields in your database.

Comment: I did not use `comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)` only use view part and it is working now. Thank you.